# Dúvida com debug do chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, iframe

Tenho esse código na minha página:

```
<iframe id="dialog1" class="ui-helper-hidden" style="width: 700px;display: inline"></iframe>
```

Porém no debug do chrome, eu tenho esses valores:

```
<iframe id="dialog1" class="ui-helper-hidden ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; display: inline; min-height: 0px; max-height: none; height: 456px;" src="../../ace/ace005a.asp?/GEN/ASP/GEN0001a.asp$$ind_situacao=&amp;tipo_empresa=&amp;ind_classificacao=&amp;p_cod_tipo_contrato=&amp;indsubmit=false&amp;txt_nome_campo_cod=num_contrato&amp;txt_nome_campo_cod_ts=cod_ts_contrato&amp;txt_nome_campo_desc=nome_contrato&amp;ind_tipo_pessoa=J&amp;funcao_executar=PesquisaContratoMontaFilial();&amp;abre_modal=S&amp;ind_alteracao_contrato=&amp;tipo_preco="></iframe>
```

Não sei de onde vem esses valores do CSS, pois é isso que está impedindo o funcionamento correto.
Qualquer ajuda é bem-vinda.

Comment: Você está utilizando o jQuery UI?

Comment: Qual seria o "funcionamento correto", e por que você acha que o problema é dessas classes?

Comment: @bfavaretto, bom dia. O funcionamento correto é que o IFrame obedecesse ao estilo aplicado a ele e isso não ocorre. Logo, tenho uma tela Modal com tamanho de 700 X 500 e um IFrame dentro dele com medidas 323 X 456 , quando na verdade deveria ter 700 X 500, pois foi o passado no estilo: style="width: 700px; heigth: 500px;". Assim está no momento no código. Pois o width está como "auto".

Answer (score 0):

Caso você esteja utilizando a framework **jQuery UI** (ou algum plugin jQuery que altera o DOM dinamicamente), é esse o motivo de ter classes que você não escreveu inicialmente na sua tag quando você inspeciona o elemento, eles estão sendo escritos programaticamente.

Pelo código você está utilizando a [Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) do jQuery UI que adiciona essas classes para poder funcionar corretamente.

Você pode remover o plugin .js (tirar a referência dele da página) ou altera-lo (procurar no código essas classes e substituir ou remover ou então remover a chamada da função que adiciona essas classes.

Comment: Laerte, como eu faço isso? Como removo ou altero? No aguardo...

Comment: Atualizei a resposta.

Comment: Mas se eu remover o include dele da página, não terei problema em executar o Modal?

Comment: Óbvio que terá, por isso que o plugin adiciona essas classes pra funcionar o que você quer, qual o problema com essas classes?

Comment: cara, me desculpe pela minha ignorância, mas não entendi nada do que você está falando, ou seja, como fazer isso.

Comment: Primeiro: por que você quer remover essas classes? Segundo: Como você está usando um plugin pra fazer o modal como você mesmo disse não vai ser possível remover, pois o plugin já faz isso automático, se você remover não terá o modal.

Comment: Eu não quero remover. Foi uma sugestão sua na resposta: "Você pode remover o plugin .js (tirar a referência dele da página) ou altera-lo (procurar no código essas classes e substituir ou remover ou então remover a chamada da função que adiciona essas classes."

Comment: Sim, dessa forma nada vai ser adicionado sem sua permissão o remover que eu me refiro é tirar a tag `<script>` que faz referência ao plugin, remover a chamada é remover algo do tipo `$("#dialog").dialog();`

Comment: Ok, agora ficou mais claro. É que na sugestão sua falou em remover aí eu disse, que isso faria com que minha tela modal nem sequer subisse.

Comment: Certo, disponha! ;)